# Geting maximum number of a filed in a json by React?

Tags: reactjs

I have series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by `fetch()` request. there is a filed in every object of json file called `totalcom`. I want to return Max value of totalcom but return me `NaN`. How can I have max and min number in Reactjs?

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        .
        .
        .
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
            method: 'get',
        }, )
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
}
reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const {
        data
    } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    .
    .
    .
}

// handle render of library
renderLibrary = () => {
    const {
        library
    } = this.state;

    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div className = "nodata" > no result < /div>
    }
    return Math.max(...library.map(item => item.totalCom), library[0].totalCom)
}
render() {
    const {
        library
    } = this.state;
    return ( <
        div > {
            this.renderLibrary()
        } < /div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Comment: Could you please try and format you code with e.g. [Prettier](https://prettier.io/)? It's very difficult to read.

Comment: totalCom is a number value? for your code is right, maybe totalCom is returning something like this "3"

Comment: The type of `totalCom` is  `Scalar.Numeric`.It is number value

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Max` returns `NaN` when some arguments cannot be converted to `Number` ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Return_value)).

Try to sanitize the values of your array and/or convert them to `Number` before applying `Math.max`

Answer (score 0):

```
    return Math.max(...library.map(item => item.totalCom), library[0].totalCom)
```

Try to debug this statement, there must be some values here which can't be converted to number